# Select your grade from the list

Tags: javascript, html, gallery, imagefilter

> so what i'm trying to do is:
> When you select a grade
> , a function will be triggered and output the book covers (images of the book covers)  of the selected grade.

```js
    const select = document.querySelector('#my');
    const img = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    
    
    select.addEventListener('change', e => {
    
        const gradeString = e.target.value;
        const url = `history covers/grade${gradeString}.jpeg`;
        // images in array so i need to loop through all of the imgs and update each one at a time
        img.src = url;
        img.alt = `grade${gradeString}`;
    })
```

```html
<p>Select your grade from the list.</p>
    
    
    <p>When you select a grade, a function is triggered which outputs the book covers of the selected grade.</p>
    
    
    
    <select id="my">
        <option class="btn" value="all">All Grades</option>
        <option class="btn" value="1">Grade 1</option>
        <option class="btn" value="2">Grade 2</option>
        <option class="btn" value="3">Grade 3</option>
        <option class="btn" value="4">Grade 4</option>
        <option class="btn" value="5">Grade 5</option>
        <option class="btn" value="6">Grade 6</option>
        <option class="btn" value="7">Grade 7</option>
        <option class="btn" value="8">Grade 8</option>
      </select>
      
      
      <img src="history covers/grade6-dor.jpeg">
      <img src="history covers/grade8.jpeg">
      <img src="history covers/grade7.jpeg">
      <img src="history covers/grade6-mahavak.jpeg">
```

Answer (score 0):

add all your images to your html and set the css to display none.  Then in your js just change the style to block for the image you want.  That image will be your gradeString - 1

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#my');
    const img = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    
    
    select.addEventListener('change', e => {
    
        const gradeString = e.target.value;
        
        img[gradeString-1].style.display='block'
       
    })
```

```css
.images{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<p>Select your grade from the list.</p>
    
    
    <p>When you select a grade, a function is triggered which outputs the book covers of the selected grade.</p>
    
    
    
    <select id="my">
        <option class="btn" value="all">All Grades</option>
        <option class="btn" value="1">Grade 1</option>
        <option class="btn" value="2">Grade 2</option>
        <option class="btn" value="3">Grade 3</option>
        <option class="btn" value="4">Grade 4</option>
        <option class="btn" value="5">Grade 5</option>
        <option class="btn" value="6">Grade 6</option>
        <option class="btn" value="7">Grade 7</option>
        <option class="btn" value="8">Grade 8</option>
      </select>
      
      
      <img class='images' src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img class='images' src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img class='images' src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img class='images' src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img class='images' src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img class='images' src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img class='images' src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
      <img class='images' src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
```